# Gradle access property from `apply from: ''` in same file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

`Error:(12, 0) Cannot get property 'kotlin' on extra properties extension as it does not exist`

My config file: `buildsystem/configurations.gradle`

```
ext {
    android = [
            buildToolsVersion: "26.0.2",
            minSdkVersion    : 23,
            targetSdkVersion : 27,
            compileSdkVersion: 27
    ]

    kotlin = [
            version      : '1.2.21',
            serialization: '0.4.1'
    ]
}
```

Top level `build.gradle`

```
apply from: 'buildsystem/configurations.gradle'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        //get kotlin version from configurations.gradle
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${rootProject.ext.kotlin.version}"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

How can I reference the `kotlin` array from the `configurations.gradle` file? I've tried what I have above, `project.ext.kotlin.version`, `ext.kotlin.version`, and just `kotlin.version`. This has to be so obvious that I'm just missing something. If I go deeper into submodule build files I can reference everything as I'd expect, but not here.

Comment: It doesn't work because gradle applies the `buildscript` blocks from your script **strictly before** executing anything else from it.  I don't know if you can move `apply from` to your `buildscript` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `buildscript` block is sort of its own script. One way to handle this is to apply the script plugin in the `buildscript` block:

```groovy
buildscript {
  apply from: 'buildsystem/configurations.gradle'
  // ... rest of buildscript configuration
```

Comment: That works. Are there any consequences that you know of from moving it into the `buildscript` block?

Comment: @Jack not really any consequences I can think of, although you may run into some issues if you switch to the `kotlin-dsl` due to https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/682.

Comment: I found that I needed to do this instead: `apply from: 'buildsystem/configurations.gradle', to: it`